# ValueError when loading model that uses lambda resize layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

So basically, I trained a model with a resize layer. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda image: tf.image.resize(
        image,
        (470,470),
        method = tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC,
        preserve_aspect_ratio = True
    )

))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=shape))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.33))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Before using the first layer, I could save and load the model, but now when loading I get this error:

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape received is (None, None, None, None), where axis -1 (0-based) is the channel dimension, which found to be `None`.
```

I loaded my data first like this:
`model2 = load_model('catsanddogs.h5')`

and also tried some solutions from a github issue that made it like this `model =load_model('catsanddogs.h5',custom_objects={"tf":tf})`

Does anyone know how to properly load this model?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what is in the shape variable ?

Comment: try using resizing layer in keras tensorflow. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Resizing

Comment: @MUKILANS its just a tuple with the shape of the image (470,470,3)

Comment: insted of lamda layer why not try a resizing layer and gave input_shape in that resizing layer and can you tell what you are predicting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that has this issue in the future, instead of using a lambda layer, use a keras resizing layer. Also the h5 file that wouldn't load still works on huggingface.